# LINQ OrderBy with IEnumerable<T> key

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable that I want to sort not within each sequence but from sequence to sequence.

```
new [] {"Z", "B", "C" }
new [] {"A", "B", "C" }
new [] {"B", "B", "C" }
```

becomes

```
new [] {"A", "B", "C" }
new [] {"B", "B", "C" }
new [] {"Z", "B", "C" }
```

Is there an existing approach with LINQ or do I need to roll my own IComparer?

Comment: Have you tried using `orderBy` with `thenBy`, chaining all the lists together?

Comment: You want to rank 3 arrays in the given example?

Comment: It's not clear from your example - are the entire rows being sorted by the first element, or is each element in each being sorted?

Comment: Provide the full declaration of your IEnumerable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built in. It's straightforward to roll your own helper method; it's one line **provided that the sequences are the same length**.

```
static int SequenceCompare<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> x, 
    IEnumerable<T> y, 
    Func<T, T, int> comparer) =>
  x.Zip(y, comparer).FirstOrDefault(c => c != 0);
```

Now if you can compare two members of a sequence, you can also compare two sequences.

This doesn't work if the sequences are of unequal length; you have to do a bit more work to say that "A", "B", "C" is "bigger" than "A", "B".

Exercise: Solve the problem for sequences of unequal length. (Hint: Examine the implementation of `Zip` and modify it accordingly.)

Exercise: Suppose we have a comparison function `Func<T, T, int>`.  We've seen how to extend it to `Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, int>`.  Now suppose the arguments were `Task<T>`, or `Func<T>` or `Nullable<T>` or `Lazy<T>` -- how might you similarly implement a comparison?  Which of those are easy and which of them are hard, and why?